# Split form field of entity property into several subfields with FormBuilder

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, formbuilder

I have one superclass which gets extended by two entities. The superclass has a N:M relation with another entity. In the formbuilder of the latter, I need to separate the two subtypes into excluding separate fields.

This is its FormType::buildForm method:

```php
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
 {
     $builder
         ->add('options_subtype_1', 'entity', [
             'class' => 'AcmeExampleBundle:Options',
             'expanded' => true,
             'multiple' => true,
             'property_path'=> 'options',
             'query_builder' => /* specific filter 1 */
         ])
         ->add('options_subtype_2', 'entity', [
             'class' => 'AcmeExampleBundle:Options',
             'expanded' => true,
             'multiple' => true,
             'property_path'=> 'options',
             'query_builder' => /* specific filter 2 */
         ])
    ;
}
```

However, no options are saved on form submission, except when I comment one of the two fields above (the one left is saved). I imagine setting `property_path` to the same property from two fields on the same form does not work.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm still searching for the perfect solution by myself. For now I handle this kind of issues with a mapped hidden field and a PRE_SUBMIT Form Event. This could look like

FormType::buildForm

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
 {
     $builder
         ->add('options_subtype_1', 'entity', [
             'class' => 'AcmeExampleBundle:Options',
             'expanded' => true,
             'multiple' => true,
             'mapped'=> false,
             'data' => $builder->getData()->getOptions(),
             'query_builder' => /* specific filter 1 */
         ])
         ->add('options_subtype_2', 'entity', [
             'class' => 'AcmeExampleBundle:Options',
             'expanded' => true,
             'multiple' => true,
             'mapped' => false,
             'data' => $builder->getData()->getOptions(),
             'query_builder' => /* specific filter 2 */
         ])
         ->add('options', 'entity', [
             'class' => 'AcmeExampleBundle:Options',
             'required' => false,
             'multiple' => true,
             'attr' => ['style' => 'visibility: hidden;'],
             'label' => false
         ]);

    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT,
        function (FormEvent $event) {
            $data = $event->getData();
            unset($data['options']);
            $data['options'] = array_merge($data['options_subtype_1'], $data['options_subtype_2']);
            $event->setData($data);
        }
    );
}
```